# Query result in nulls on CI oci8 with SQLDeveloper it returns values

Tags: sql, oracle, codeigniter, oracle-call-interface

I have problem with my query on C, I’m using the oci8 driver.  This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE FIRST_NAME like '%BRUCEE%' AND BIRTH_DATE like '28-DEC-72'
```

In SQLDeveloper I execute the query and it has an output, but while I execute it via CI I get a return null array returned.

FIRSTNAME = VARCHAR2
BIRTH_DATE = DATE (DD-MON-YY)

Can anybody help me with this CI query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue with different tools setting a different `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for the session.  Try using an ANSI date literal instead to avoid any possible conversion issues:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE FIRST_NAME like '%BRUCEE%'
  AND trunc(BIRTH_DATE) = date '1972-12-28'
```